# How do you package a ruby application for offline installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an intranet server with no internet access that I need to deploy a RoR application on it.

My process will be to download Ruby, install it, download Rails, install it, etc. But I have multiple gems in my Gemfile I'd like to install. How can I get these on the intranet server? Do I have to download them all separately, or is there there a way to package them up?

Comment: There is [documentation](http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network) on this subject. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks! Can you do this with a whole gemfile? or `gem fetch` them one at a time?

Comment: I'm not sure of the specific procedure to grab all referenced gems and their dependencies, but there's probably a way to do that. `Gemfile.lock` contains an exhaustive list of what's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell bundler to vendor all the gems needed for your app, by running:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

That will create a `vendor` directory in the root of your application. Make sure you include this directory when moving the app to the standalone server. You will still need to install Ruby, RubyGems, and the bundler gem.

For Ruby and RubyGems you can download their respective installers. You can download a copy of the bundler with `gem fetch`

```
gem fetch bundler
```

This will download a gem file like `bundler-1.6.5.gem`, which you can install on the standalone server with:

```
gem install bundler-1.6.5.gem
```