# Releasing Ruby Application for Specific users

Tags: ruby, package, release

I am new to `Ruby` and I have written a small app, that consists of around 50 `.rb` files and 6 folders. The purpose of app is to be an `SDK` for Ruby users, to interact with my `API`. It also uses few gems. Now I want to release this app for specific users, but looking at the internet for the solution really confused me *(may be just because I'm new to it)* and MOST of the posts found were for `Rails`

Being through several posts, what I find to be reasonable is to make a `gem` out of it and publish this `gem` at `rubygems.org`. *(but this also makes it fully public)*

**Question:**

- Is this the correct approach in my specific scenario?
- How can I manage the dependencies? *(This part is very confusing, I will need more guidelines on this)*
- How to limit audience? *(I have personal git server, would this be of any help)*

*Other Info:*

- App is developed in Ruby version `2.1.8`, It makes `http` `Get`/`Post` requests using `TLS`, and is **NOT** a `Rails` or web app
- I have been through several SO posts like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940877/how-do-you-package-a-ruby-application-for-offline-installation), [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145599/how-to-package-and-release-a-ruby-application) etc. But I couldn't understand it for my case.
- I created a project in [Jetbrains' IDE, called RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). My project doesn't have bin folder, etc. but only my own folders and `.rb` files. And most of the solutions also talk about bin.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @jbhannah Restricting download access to the gem isn't foolproof. People could theoretically start distributing pirated copies. Best to also make the gem's functionality contingent on an API token which is granted as part of a user's being authorized to use the API. This is how most API gems work anyway. For example, to use a Google API gem you'd need to enter a valid Google developer token.

Answer (score 0):

[Gemfury](https://gemfury.com/) is probably what you're looking for. You'll package your library as a gem the same way as if you were going to publish it publicly on RubyGems, but Gemfury lets you restrict access to it to only the people you want to allow.